# Devise gem admin can add user into user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `devise` gem for authentication in Rails. I want to create a admin dashboard that can add user into `User` model. I am able to render form into `admin#index` view, but I am not able to insert data in user model.

routes.rb

```rb
# when i use post method in this route i get routing error 
get '/admin' => "admin#index", as: :create_user
```

Admin index.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_for User.new, url: create_user_path do |f| %>

<div class="log-in-form">
  <h2 class="login-header text-center">Sign up</h2>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

admin_controller.rb

```rb
def index
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if User.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

  private

  def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password)
end
```

Comment: 1- Please state exact errors or server logs for requests.
2- It seems you have not defined route for create action in routes, and are using create_user_path in form defination which would give no route matches errors on form submission. Fix the routes(add a new post route for `admin#create` properly) and you can than proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, you badly need to read and understand this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

**Answer:**

You have defined the route as a `get` method yourself and you are expecting to `post` to it. Do you see something very odd here?
As a beginner, try not to deviate from basic CRUD routes that rails provides for you. In your case, do this in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users

# OR:
# resources :users, only: %i[index show create update destroy]
# any names of CRUD functions that you probably will use (to avoid extra routes)
```

Now, in your html file change `url: create_user_path` to `url: users_path`.
BTW, at least make it a habit to check your routes in terminal like in your case: `rails routes | grep user` will give you the rails routes having word user in them.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your config/routes.rb

```
post '/admin' => 'admin#index'
```